# Why was an older version of Nginx installed?

Tags: nginx, debian, php-fpm, php5, debian-wheezy

I installed Nginx and PHP5-FPM and have it all working, but I noticed that I have Nginx 1.2.1 installed and not the most recent stable version (1.6.x). I also noticed that PHP-FPM had PHP 5.4 and not PHP 5.5. However, that is not as much a security problem as the old Nginx version.

How I installed:

1. Added `deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I also correctly added the PGP key.
2. `su`
3. `apt-get update` The Nginx server was listed during the update and there were no errors.
4. `apt-get install nginx-extras php5-fpm`
5. I then configured both to my liking. I also realized I had an old version of Nginx.
6. I did `apt-cache show nginx-common` and saw the old version.
7. I tried `apt-get upgrade` to no avail.

Output of `apt-cache show nginx-common`:

```
Package: nginx-common
Source: nginx
Version: 1.2.1-2.2+wheezy3
Installed-Size: 203
Maintainer: Kartik Mistry <kartik@debian.org>
Architecture: all
Replaces: nginx (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-extras (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-full (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-light (<< 0.8.54-4)
Depends: lsb-base (>= 3.2-14)
Breaks: nginx (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-extras (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-full (<< 0.8.54-4), nginx-light (<< 0.8.54-4)
Description-en: small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
 Nginx ("engine X") is a high-performance web and reverse proxy server
 created by Igor Sysoev. It can be used both as a standalone web server
 and as a proxy to reduce the load on back-end HTTP or mail servers.
 .
 This package contains base configuration files used by all versions of
 nginx.
Homepage: http://nginx.net
Description-md5: 9e23931d84d07adbee5412aefdad8a90
Tag: role::app-data
Section: httpd
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/n/nginx/nginx-common_1.2.1-2.2+wheezy3_all.deb
Size: 72790
MD5sum: 45164faa28f8937d2864d1ccb5a8787f
SHA1: ff54c828017f7866cc84cf23eb54e516a07f81a8
SHA256: 3c87c9377d66c574c45c977a602fa01d26e57b89b7cb1a8751fee4ab8f0e1225
```

Debian Wheezy 7.7 i686-pae

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed the wrong packages.

You've added [the upstream nginx repository](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html) to your server, but in this repo the nginx package is simply named `nginx`. There are no other packages to install; those are Debian-specific (and often confusing).

To resolve the problem, remove the packages you installed, then install the nginx package.

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx-common nginx-extras
sudo apt-get autoremove  ## optional
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Before I purge my old installation, do you know of any up-to-date packages of `nginx-extras` that include all of the extensions? I don't want to have to build it myself if I end up neededing any of them.

Comment: As far as I know, the `nginx` package from upstream contains all modules that are in `nginx-extras` except the third-party modules.

Comment: I just did `apt-cache show nginx` and still got 1.2.1-2.2+wheezy3

Comment: **Nevermind!** There were two listed. I only read the bottom one. Thank you.